# I cannot understand this proof of equivalent statements for continuity

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, proof-explanation

We are showing that the following statements are equivalent:

Let $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with $x_o \in E$ and $E \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. Let $x_o$ be an accumulation point of $E$.

1.) $f$ is continuous at $x_o$

2.) $f$ has a limit at $x_o$ and $\lim_{x \to x_{o}} f(x) = f(x_{o})$

3.) For every sequence $\{ x_{n} \}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ that converges to $x_{o}$, with $x_{n} \in E$ for all $n$, $\{f(x_{n})\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to $f(x_{o})$

I do not understand our proof that 3 $\Rightarrow$ 2. I will give it below and mark the statement I find problematic with "**".

---

PROOF:

Suppose (3) is true.
So, if $x_{n} \rightarrow x_{o}$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, with $x_{n} \neq x_{o}$, with $x_{n} \in E$ for all $n$, then $\{f(x_{n})\}^{\infty}_{n=1}$ converges to $f(x_{o})$.

By way of contradiction, suppose $\lim_{x \to x_{o}} f(x) \neq f(x_{o})$

(*) Then $\exists \epsilon > 0$ st $\forall \delta > 0$, $\exists x \in E$ with $0 < |x - x_{o}| < \delta$ and $|f(x) - f(x_{o}) | \geq \epsilon$.

(**) In particular, for each positive integer $n$, $\exists x_{n} \in E$ with $|x_{n} - x_{o}| < \frac{1}{n}$ st $|f(x) - f(x_{o})| \geq \epsilon$.

Since $x_{n} \rightarrow x_{o}$, and for each $x_{n} \in E$, we know $f(x_{n}) \rightarrow f(x_{o})$, we have a contradiction.

Therefore, $f(x) \rightarrow f(x_{o})$ as $x \rightarrow x_{o}$ and $f$ has a limit at $x_{o}$.

---

I find the marked statement very problematic. Firstly, it seems strange to say "for every $n$, there exists an $x_{n}$ such that.." since a choice of $n$ determines $x_{n}$. If I said "let $n = 7$", then from this I could deduce that "there exists an $x_{7}$ such that ..." but $x_{7}$ is a specific member of the sequence, so what do we mean there "exists" an $x_{7}$?

Secondly, even if I "get over it," how can I pick my $\delta$ to be $\frac{1}{n}$? - this is what's done. I understand that the statement is "for any delta," but I don't understand how I can pick a delta whose value is determined by the position of the sequence, because that's not just a statement of "any delta", because this $n$ is already in use.

Comment: You have a good point. It should say $\forall n\in N\;\exists m_n$ with  $ |x_{m_n}-x_0|<1/n$ ...(etc) , or simply  $\forall n\in N\;\exists m$ with $|x_m-x_0|<1/n$....

Answer (score 2):

As you wrote: $\forall \delta > 0$, $\exists x \in E$ with $0 < |x - x_{o}| < \delta$, etc.
Now apply what you wrote:

Since it holds for all $\delta$, choose $\delta=1/n$ (where $n$ is a positive integer) and for that $\delta$ take $x$ with $0 < |x - x_{o}| < 1/n$, etc (you know that $x$ exists because of the second quantifier). Simply you then decide to denote this particular $x$ by $x_n$.

Comment: Oh - haha! So $x_{n}$ is NOT the nth member of the sequence, it is what we are calling the particular $x$ that is guaranteed by the first statement. That's pretty confusing notation to me, but this seems ok.

Comment: His problem, I am not mistaken, is that he does not understand the wording "for each $n$, there exists $x_{n}$" since $n$ fixes $x_{n}$ (because $x_{n}$ only depends on $n$, obviously, since a sequence of real numbers is nothing but a function from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$). The thing is there is a mistake: the index $k$ for which $\vert x_{k}-x_{0}\vert<\frac{1}{n}$ need not be equal to $n$.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer you two are saying the same thing, I think. Your confusion is the same as mine, we simply aren't using $x_{n}$ to denote the nth member of the sequence here, we're using it exactly as your $x_{k}$. If $n = 7$, this $x_{n}$ does NOT denote $x_{7}$, it denotes the/an $x$ such that $|x - x_{o}|  < \frac{1}{7}$. Hopefully Jonas can confirm that I understand him.

Comment: I understand but I don't say the same thing as Jonas since I think what he says is false. A sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is nothing but a function, say $f$, from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Writing the same $n$ is wrong. It is another $n$ (and you have understood it) but you can't write the same $n$ since $x_{n}$ is the value of the function $f$ evaluated at $n$. It would be like saying, for any $y$, there exists $f(y)$ such that (...). When you write $f(y)$, you explicitly means the function $f$ evaluated in the given $y$, not another $y$ than the previous one.

Comment: We are not saying the same thing. Simply, for the proof you need one $x_n$ for each given $n$, that's is, not need for something like $x_k$.

Comment: Ok, let's say $x_{n}=\tfrac{1}{n}$ for any $n\geq 2$ and $x_{1}=10^{1000}$. It is clear that this sequence converges to $x_{0}=0$. Now, for $n=1$, we have to find a number $x_{k}$ in the sequence such that $\vert x_{k} - 0\vert <\frac{1}{n}=1$. If you take $x_{n}=x_{1}$, it obviously does not work.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Again, here, $x_{n}$ is not standing for the nth member of the sequence, in the same way that $x_{0}$ is not standing for the "zeroth member" of the sequence. Here, if $n = 1$, then $x_{n}$ is NOT denoting $x_{1}$, it is denoting some member of the sequence $x$ that satisfies $|x - x_{o}| < \frac{1}{1}$. You are taking it to mean both of these things (as I did) and that's why you're saying it's false.

Comment: Let me add the following, which is perhaps what @MoebiusCorzer is missing: we are assuming that (3) holds for any sequence as in that statement; the argument to show that (3) implies (2) goes by contradiction: we need to find ONE sequence for each the statement (3) fails and that it done as I explained; since statement (3) says that the opposite holds for ALL sequences, it also holds for that specific sequence, and thus the contradiction.

Comment: @Jonas Ok, you are right. I read too fast. The point of the proof is to construct a sequence converging to $x_{0}$ such that $f(x_{n})$ does not converge to $f(x_{0})$. My apologies for that.
Still, I disagree with the "simply you just denote it $x_{n}$". We do that to construct a sequence for which it does not work.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer I don't understand your objection. You used $x_{K(n)}$ in your comment in the exact same way that Jonas/the proof is using $x_{n}$. Besides the ambiguous notation (since $x_{n}$ usually means the nth member of the sequence), what is your objection?

Comment: @JonathanHebert He is right when he says that I was missing something. We do more than "simply decide to denote this particular $x$ by $x_{n}$". The point is to construct a sequence, which is a well-defined concept, not a notation. For any $\delta$, there exists an $x$, depending on $\delta$ (so we can construct a function $\delta\mapsto x(\delta)$) verifying the inequality. In particular, if we take $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$, we explicitly construct a sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ such that $x_{n}\to x_{0}$ but $f(x_{n})\not\to f(x_{0})$.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, my apologies to Jonas because I thought what he was saying was wrong. Thank you for having corrected me.

Secondly, I detail here why the proof is valid since I disagree with the "simply decide to denote this particular $x$ by $x_{n}$" sentence in the Jonas' answer, which tends to insinuate that it is just a notation.

Let $x_{0}$ be an accumulation point of $E$. We want to prove that, if for any sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n}\subset E$ converging to $x_{0}$, we have $f(x_{n})$ converges to $f(x_{0})$, then $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f(x)=f(x_{0})$.

By contradiction, we suppose that $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f(x)\neq f(x_{0})$. We want to construct a sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ converging to $x_{0}$ but such that $f(x_{n})$ does not converge to $f(x_{0})$, which will be a contradiction.

The fact that $\lim_{x\to x_{0}}f(x)\neq f(x_{0})$ is, by definition, equivalent to:

$$\exists\epsilon>0:\forall\delta>0,\exists x\in E:\vert x-x_{0}\vert<\delta\implies \vert f(x)-f(x_{0})\vert\geq\epsilon$$

The part where it says $\forall\delta>0,\exists x\in E$ means that to any $\delta>0$, we can associate at least one $x$ such that $\vert x-x_{0}\vert<\delta\implies \vert f(x)-f(x_{0})\vert\geq\epsilon$. In other words, it means that we can construct a function $\Delta:\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}\to E:\delta\mapsto \Delta(\delta):=x_{\delta}$ such that for any $\delta\in\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$, we have

$$\vert x_{\delta}-x_{0}\vert=\vert \Delta(\delta)-x_{0}\vert<\delta\implies\vert f(x_{\delta})-f(x_{0})\vert=\vert f(\Delta(\delta))-f(x_{0})\vert\geq\epsilon$$

A sequence of real numbers is a function $\mathbb{N}_{0}\to\mathbb{R}$. As $\mathbb{N}_{0}\subset\mathbb{R}^{+}_{0}$, by restricting ourselves to $\delta=\frac{1}{n}$, we obtain a sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n}=\{\Delta(\tfrac{1}{n})\}_{n}$. By construction, we have

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}_{0}:x_{n}\in E\text{ and }\vert x_{n}-x_{0}\vert\le\frac{1}{n} $$

which means $x_{n}\to x_{0}$, so that $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$ is a sequence of points in $E$ converging to $x_{0}$. Hence, by assumption, we have $f(x_{n})\to f(x_{0})$.

On the other hand, by construction of this particular sequence $\{x_{n}\}_{n}$, we have

$$\exists\epsilon>0:\forall N\in\mathbb{N}_{0},\exists n\geq N: \vert f(x_{n})-f(x_{0})\vert\geq\epsilon$$

which means that $f(x_{n})\not\to f(x_{0})$, hence we have a contradiction.